# Can I include Java code with VB.NET code?

Tags: java, vb.net

How can I include a Java code with VB.NET code?

Comment: What do you mean by include a java code with vb.net code? Do you mean run java code from within a vb.net app and the other way around?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?
Call Java from VB.NET?
Call VB.NET from Java?

Comment: Call java inside VB.NET that's what i ment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want to run java code inside vb.net or vice versa, the way I would do it is by launching a new java process from VB.net or launching the vb.net app executable from Java (both would require your apps being compiled before launching them, however).

To launch a new process from Java, consider:

- [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

  Example: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myVBApp.exe");`
- [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

  Example: `ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBulder("myVBApp.exe");`

To launch a new process from VB.Net, consider:

- [Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk.aspx)

  Example: `Shell("java myJavaApp")`
- [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

  Example: `Process.Start("java","myJavaApp")`

All examples would require some more code if you want to do anything more meaningful than just launch the process, but the links ought to point you in the right direction.

As for your real player plugin question, that probably warrants a separate question. Best to keep each question on one topic.